# IE9 Displaying Flash at 0,0 or not at all

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-9, swfobject

So out of all the browsers I have access to IE9 is displaying old-style object embedded Flash code at left:0; top:0; All other browsers, including IE 8 have no issues at all.

http://www.ericaspindler.com/bookshelf/index.bak.php

But if I upgrade to using swfobject IE 8 and 9 simply display an empty space:

http://www.ericaspindler.com/bookshelf/index.php

But Chrome, Safari, and FireFox are all happily displaying the Flash.

Anyone else seen this issue?  Any ideas on how to solve?

Update:  Known issue -

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/05/reported-issues-with-flash-player-10-3-and-internet-explorer-9.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue:

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/05/reported-issues-with-flash-player-10-3-and-internet-explorer-9.html